# Formula for Hessian of hypersurface in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

This is essentially asking again the following question: [Formula for the induced Hessian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344526/formula-for-the-induced-hessian), which never received an answer. Below I record my thoughts.

For $\Sigma^{n-1}\subset M^n$, I want to show $$|\nabla^2_\Sigma u|^2=|\nabla^2 u|^2-2|\nabla|\nabla u||^2+|\nabla^2 u(\nu,\nu)|^2.$$ Since this is an equality of functions, it suffices to show this equality pointwise. Therefore, we use geodesic normal coordinates, with $e_n=\nu$. The LHS in coordinates becomes
$$\text{LHS}=\sum_{i,j}^{n-1}u_{ij}^2,$$
while the RHS in coordinates (I hope) becomes
\begin{align*}
\text{RHS}&=\left(\sum_{i,j}^nu_{ij}^2\right)-2\sum_{i=1}^nu_{in}+u_{nn}^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n-1}u_{ij}^2+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_{in}^2+u_{nn}^2\right)-2\sum_{i=1}^nu_{in}+u_{nn}^2\\
&=\text{LHS}
\end{align*}
Thus, the only term requiring justification is why in geodesic normal coordinates,
$$|\nabla|\nabla u||^2=\sum_{i=1}^n u_{in}^2.$$
We compute this term by using
$$|\nabla v|^2= \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2,$$
with $v=|\nabla u|$, and also
$$|\nabla u|_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{u_{j}u_{ij}}{|\nabla u|}.$$
Altogether, we must show
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{u_ju_{ij}}{|\nabla u|}\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n u_{in}^2.$$
Is there a mistake somewhere, or can someone help me finish the last step in the computation?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The answer relies on a simple calc 3 observation.

The computation finishes upon realizing that for the level set is    perpendicular to the gradient, so $|\nabla u|=u_n$ (i.e. $u_j=0$ for    $j=1,...,n-1$). Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{u_ju_{ij}}{|\nabla u|}\right)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{u_nu_{in}}{|\nabla u|}\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nu_{in}^2.
\end{align*}

If anyone can produce a coordinate-free proof, I'd be happy to accept your answer. In particular, I would be interested to see if there's a way to express that $\Sigma$ is perpendicular to $\nabla u$ without coordinates.

Comment: An alternate approach is to use the implicit function theorem to first write the hypersurface implicitly as $0=r(x,y)= y- f(x)$ where $y=f(x)$ is the explicit local description. The hessian relation in this  case is especially easy to compute.Then compute how this  Hessian relation is affected by switching to any other alternative formula $ 0 =\tilde r(x,y)$ where WLOG $\tilde r= e^h r(x,y)$ is a nonzero multiple of the nicest case